# Doubts on some combinatory problems.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

1. You have 3 literature books, 2 informatics books and 1 math book. How many ways can you order them if you want the literature books close to the math ones?
   The solution is: $2\cdot 3!\cdot 3!$. Why is that? For me it is $2\cdot 2$ if I want that the literature books remain compact, whereas $2\cdot 4!$ if that doesn't matter.
2. 10 copies of a book are distributed among 5 schools. How many ways can we do that if each school receives at least one book? Solution: combination with repetition if the books are equal, $5!\cdot 5^5$ if they are different.
3. How many ways can we assign 8 professors to 4 different schools if each school receives at least one professor? Solution: $4^8-4\cdot 3^8-6\cdot 2^8-4$.

Which is the difference between the problems 2 and 3?

Some suggestions on the first problem?

Comment: In $\#3$ presumably the professors are distinct people, while in $\#2$ the books are indistinguishable.

Comment: But also if they are different the solutions are different, as I wrote

Comment: I don't understand.  Of course the solutions are different if the problems are different.  But in $\#2$ it is specified that we are dealing with "copies of a book", which I take to mean that they are indistinguishable.  Your solution, in the "distinct book" case does not appear to be correct.

Comment: So if they are distinct books, I have to proceed like in the professor problem?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I was convinced by the solution that the book gave me (different books) since 5 books are "fixed" (then I have to permutate them, so $5!$) and for the other 5 books I have 5 possibilities ($5^5$)

Comment: I don't understand.  Which $5$ books are "fixed"?  There are many ways to choose those.  And how do you distinguish between the ones you fix initially and the ones which are later assigned randomly?

Comment: Should have said:  In the proposed solution for $\#3$ you appear to be trying to use Inclusion-Exclusion.  That's a good idea in this case, though, to use that, the signs should alternate.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion on the first problem?

Comment: I don't know what "close" means in this context.  I guess $LLML$ counts?  Does $LLLM$?  Anyway, once you decide what close means, just list all the good patterns.

Comment: Question 1 is not written clearly.  In problem 2, if the books are different, then you should use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.   As lulu said, in problem 3, the signs should alternate when you use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: I never used this principle with these problems, so it's not so clear for me

Comment: "Question 1 is not written clearly." I definitely agree with the comment of @N.F.Taussig In fact, if the solution of $2 \times 3! \times 3!$ had not been provided, I would not have given my *reverse engineered answer*.  My answer only provides a plausible interpretation to the ambiguously (i.e. poorly) written problem that is consistent with the *supposed* solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can reverse engineer a solution to problem number 1.

First, the 3 literature books can be permuted in $3!$ ways.

Then, there are exactly $2$ slots **inside** the group of 3 literature books for the math book to be placed.

Once the math book is placed inside of the three literature books, you can construe the 4 books as if they were **fused together into 1 unit**.

Then, you have the 1 unit-fused, and 2 informatics books that each represent a separate *unit*.

Thus, at the end, there are $3!$ ways of permuting these 3 *units*.

This explains the computation of $3! \times 2 \times 3!.$

Comment: Thank you very much!